# Level-triggered or edge-triggered?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll

I have a server application that listens to a port, accepts (TCP) peer connections, and then for each socket it

1) `reads` (no more than 30 bytes of data)

2) `sends` (1 byte ack)

3) `reads` (no more than 2K)

4) `sends` (1 byte ack)

5) `closes` (connection)

I use `epoll` loop in my application. I want `epoll_wait` to return (with event list with EPOLLIN flags) **only when all data arrived** from a peer, so that I could read with a single `read/recv` call into array. If all data has not been received on a certain socket fd I don't want `epoll` to add this fd to the event list.

As far as I understand differences between level-triggered and edge-triggered modes of `epoll` this behavior can be reached using edge-triggered `epoll` with nonblocking sockets plus finite states to keep track of steps.

Please correct me if I am wrong with the edge-triggered option. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible to set the minimum number of bytes available in the incoming socket buffer before `epoll_wait` reports the socket ready for read.

[man socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

> SO_RCVLOWAT and SO_SNDLOWAT
>
> Specify the minimum number of bytes in the buffer until the socket layer will pass the data to the protocol (SO_SNDLOWAT) or the user on receiving (SO_RCVLOWAT). These two values are initialized to 1. SO_SNDLOWAT is not changeable on Linux (setsockopt(2) fails with the error ENOPROTOOPT). SO_RCVLOWAT is changeable only since Linux 2.4. **The select(2) and poll(2) system calls currently do not respect the SO_RCVLOWAT setting on Linux, and mark a socket readable when even a single byte of data is available.** A subsequent read from the socket will block until SO_RCVLOWAT bytes are available.

Unless the man page is out of date.

Comment: Do you mean that regardless of level or edge triggered mode, there is possibility that I may read only, say, 1K (partial reading), and then later I will have to read the rest of data, say 1K?

Comment: @fade2black Exactly that, they report the socket ready for read when at least 1 byte is available.

Comment: It's TCP, an octet/byte-stream protocol.  It cannot transfer messages longer than one byte.

Comment: So, in edge triggered mode arrived data is notified only once, I must read it since next time epoll_wait won't notify me. How about with level triggered? It will notify me about the same data every time epoll_wait return (until next part of data arrives in), right?